# Adding facebook comments plugin in your own wordpress theme.

Tags: php, facebook, wordpress

It's the first time I try to create my own wordpress theme.
I was following this tutorial: http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development
So far, so good... but when I try to add a facebook comments plugin, it doesn't work, I can't see any comments, not even the facebook box, that means, nothing happens.
It works fine for other themes, but for mine it doesn't.

Looking at the other themes I couldn't find the exact part of the code that it's included, I see that it's rendered by the function **the_content**, but my code has the same and it doesn't work for me.
I suppose that this function should work to render the normal wordpress comments too... but I need to call it manually after this call.

I've tried to add manually the javascript code for the facebook comments, and it works doing this way... except that it doesn't integrate with the rest of the theme (like showing the right number of comments), so I don't think it's a good solution.

As I followed that tutorial the code is pretty simple.
index.php: http://pastebin.com/vxx16L1T

sidebar.php: http://pastebin.com/7mKqmAMb

header.php: http://pastebin.com/wThiaZyp

footer.php: http://pastebin.com/3sFgXHLX

Any idea about what I can do to show the comments? Let me know if you need more information.

Comment: What facebook comments plugin are you using? Facebook's drop-in iframe code? Or a WordPress plugin? If it's a WordPress plugin, it probably replaces the default comment template. For that to work, you'll need to include `comments_template()`. http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/comments_template

Comment: It's wordpress plugins... I've tried 2 of them, one that seems to be official.

I've tried to add comments_template() but with no success =/

Comment: It worked after add the javascript initialization code manually, but it doesn't seem to be right thing to do, probably there's something missing somewhere.